# OptionsResolver: How to validate sub-options following an unknown options tree

Tags: arrays, validation, symfony

**SCENARIO**

I'm writing a class to rendere as a plain text table a matrix of data represented by an array.

A simple array would be as this:

```
$data = [
    [
        'title'  => '20.000 Leghe sotto i mari',
        'author' => 'Jules Verne',
        'review'=> 'Una misteriosa creatura marina che affonda navi da guerra di ogni paese...'
    ],
    [
        'title'  => 'Il signore degli anelli: La compagnia dell\'anello',
        'author' => 'J. R. R. Tolkien',
        'review' => 'In questo primo romanzo della trilogia di Tolkien, il lettore conosce gli Hobbit...'
    ],
    [
        'title'  => 'Il leviatano',
        'author' => 'T. Hobbes contraddittorietà',
        'review' => 'Vitale rappresentazione dello Stato moderno, longeva e barocca figura di pensiero politico nelle sembianze di un mostro biblico...'
    ]
];
```

In practice, each key is the name of the column, so, in the end, I get a table like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 20.000 Leghe sotto i mari                         | Jules Verne                 | Una misteriosa creatura marina che affonda navi da guerra di ogni paese...                                                         |
+---------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Il signore degli anelli: La compagnia dell'anello | J. R. R. Tolkien            | In questo primo romanzo della trilogia di Tolkien, il lettore conosce gli Hobbit...                                                |
+---------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Il leviatano                                      | T. Hobbes contraddittorietà | Vitale rappresentazione dello Stato moderno, longeva e barocca figura di pensiero politico nelle sembianze di un mostro biblico... |
+---------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now, I want to be able to define the max width of each single column and to do so, I want to pass an array like this:

```
// The array containing the data
$options = [
    'columns' => [
        'review' => [
            'max_width' => 50
        ]
    ]
];
```

I'm defining an option called `columns` (known option) where I set the `max_width` option (known option`for the column`review` (UNKNOWN OPTION).

I know that the `columns` option can be only an `array` and that the `max_width` option can be only an `integer` but **how can I validate this with the [`OptionsResolver` component of Symfony]**[1](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html)?

This is the current implementation I have of the options:

```
/**
 * @param array $options
 */
private function resolveOptions(array $options = [])
{
    $resolver = new OptionsResolver();
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        // The horizontal separator
        'sep_h' => '-',
        // The vertical separator
        'sep_v' => '|',
        // The cross separator
        'sep_x' => '+',
        // The number of spaces to put on the left and on the right of the content of each cell
        'cells_padding' => [
            // Top padding
            1,
            // Right padding
            1,
            // Bottom padding
            1,
            // Left padding
            1
        ]
    ])
        // This options can be passed or not
        ->setDefined('columns');

    // Set type validation
    $resolver->setAllowedTypes('sep_h', 'string')
        ->setAllowedTypes('sep_v', 'string')
        ->setAllowedTypes('sep_x', 'string')
        ->setAllowedTypes('cells_padding', 'array')
        ->setAllowedTypes('columns', 'array')
        // Here use wrong validation to trigger an error as I'm passing
        // an integer that is the correct value type
        ->setAllowedTypes('max_width', 'string');

    $this->options = $resolver->resolve($options);
}
```

([Full code on GitHub](https://github.com/Aerendir/PHPTextMatrix))

So, again, how can validate this structure of options?

As you can see, I'm now setting the accepted value for `max_width` as `string` and I'm passing the right `integer` value: this could trigger an exception but it isn't. Correctly, I think, as the option is deeper in the tree, but I don't understand how to check it. Should have I to create a lot of sub `$resolvers` to validate each node of the options tree? is this the correct approach or am I missing something?

Comment: Why don't you add separate form fields for the title, author and review? That way you can define separate rules for them. Otherwise the solution would be to make the "parent" a collection, and make the collection's children the sub-type with these fields.

Comment: I'm not using it with symfony forms. I'm using it in a stand alone class that has some options to handle to do what it is meant to do. No forms.

Comment: Okay clear, then the part about validating sub-entities still applies. The form component would use the validator component on the entities, if the form is gone you can still use that validator component but you'll have to write the glue for it yourself: http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

Comment: No, I think you are not understanding what I'm doing: I have no validation, and I never have a form. I only have a `$data` array representing a matrix. If you see the code on github you'll have all clear (https://github.com/Aerendir/PHPTextMatrix/blob/master/example/example.php).